# Mismatched dimensions on 'shuffled' NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I am more or less a Python novice, working on an audio analog to this [evolutionary Mona Lisa](http://rogeralsing.com/2008/12/07/genetic-programming-evolution-of-mona-lisa/) experiment.

The below code is intended to:

1. Read a given .wav file into a NumPy array.
2. Detect 'zero crossings' in the waveform, i.e. when an array element changes sign. Split the array into a nested list of waveform 'chunks' at these points.
3. Separate positive from negative chunks, then shuffle these chunks and recombine them into a NumPy array, alternating positive with negative. I can't use random.shuffle(), since the list has well over 2000 elements.
4. Compare the 'fitness' of the shuffled array
   with the original sample, defined as the square of the difference
   between the shuffled array and original sample.

Ultimately, I'll add replication, mutation, and selection, but for now there's a problem with my fitness function. The split, shuffled, and recombined array is of different dimensions than the original input, resulting in the following error:

```
$ ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1273382) (1138213)
```

The dimensions of the second array vary each time I run the program, but are always around 1138000-1145000. I seem to have lost a few chunks during the split, shuffle, and recombination steps, and I suspect that I'm using a list comprehension incorrectly somewhere in step 3, but I can't quite figure out where or why. What's gone wrong?

```
# Import scipy audio tools, numpy, and randomization tools
import scipy
from scipy.io import wavfile

import numpy

from random import shuffle, randint

# Read a wav file data array, detect zero crossings, split at zero crossings, and return a nested list.
def process_wav(input):

    # Assign the wavefile data array to a variable.
    wavdata = input[1]

    # Detect zero crossings, i.e. changes in sign in the waveform data. The line below returns an array of the indices of elements after which a zero crossing occurs.
    zerocrossings = numpy.where(numpy.diff(numpy.sign(wavdata)))[0]
    # Increment each element in the array by one. Otherwise, the indices are off.
    zerocrossings = numpy.add(numpy.ones(zerocrossings.size, zerocrossings.dtype), zerocrossings)

    wavdatalist = wavdata.tolist()
    zerocrossingslist = zerocrossings.tolist()

    # Split the list at zero crossings. The function below splits a list at the given indices.      
    def partition(alist, indices):
        return [alist[i:j] for i, j in zip([0]+indices, indices+[None])]

    return partition(wavdatalist, zerocrossingslist)


# Accept a list as input, separate into positive and negative chunks, shuffle, and return a shuffled nested list
def shuffle_wav(list):

    # Separate waveform chunks into positive and negative lists.
    positivechunks = []
    negativechunks = []

    for chunk in list:
        if chunk[0] < 0:
            negativechunks.append(chunk)
        elif chunk[0] > 0:
            positivechunks.append(chunk)
        elif chunk[0] == 0:
            positivechunks.append(chunk)

    # Shuffle the chunks and append them to a list, alternating positive with negative.
    shuffledchunks = []
    while len(positivechunks) >= 0 and len(negativechunks) > 0:
        currentpositivechunk = positivechunks.pop(randint(0, len(positivechunks)-1))
        shuffledchunks.append(currentpositivechunk)
        currentnegativechunk = negativechunks.pop(randint(0, len(negativechunks)-1))
        shuffledchunks.append(currentnegativechunk)

    return [chunk for sublist in shuffledchunks for chunk in sublist]

def get_fitness(array, target):
    return numpy.square(numpy.subtract(target, array))

# Read a sample wav file. The wavfile function returns a tuple of the file's sample rate and data as a numpy array, to be passed to the process_wav() function.
input = scipy.io.wavfile.read('sample.wav')     

wavchunks = process_wav(input)  
shuffledlist = shuffle_wav(wavchunks)   
output = numpy.array(shuffledlist, dtype='int16')
print get_fitness(output, input[1])

scipy.io.wavfile.write('output.wav', 44100, output)
```

EDIT: Here's the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "evowav.py", line 64, in <module>
    print get_fitness(output, input[1])
  File "evowav.py", line 56, in get_fitness
    return numpy.square(numpy.subtract(target, array))
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1273382) (1136678)`
```

Comment: Please always include the COMPLETE traceback, or we can't help, because we are just guessing what or why something should happen.

Comment: Apologies. I added the full traceback above.

Comment: Do you have a link to the .wav file you are using, so we can reproduce it?

Comment: The basic problem looks to be in the shuffling logic. If there are not the same number of positive and negative chunks in the input list, a chunk will always be missing from the output. That leads to the input and output being different sizes, resulting in the failure you see.

Comment: @ecmendenhall - Also, there's no need to use things like `numpy.square(numpy.subtract(target, array))`. It's much more pythonic (and exactly equivalent) to use `(target - array)**2` Similarly, `zerocrossings = numpy.add(numpy.ones(zerocrossings.size, zerocrossings.dtype), zerocrossings)` is equivalent to `zerocrossings += 1`. (Actually the latter is slightly more efficient, as it will modify the array in-place.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, let's clean up some of your code.

1. Don't overwrite python builtin functions such as `list` and `input` by using them as variable names.  Python doesn't strictly prevent it, but it will cause surprises later.
2. There's no need to explicitly call things like `z = numpy.add(x, y)`.  `z = x + y` is much more pythonic and exactly equivalent. (Assuming that `x` and `y` are numpy arrays.)  Similarly, there's no need to make a new array of ones just to add 1 to each item in a numpy array.  Just call `x += 1` or `x = x + 1` if you want a copy.
3. Instead of putting comments about what the function does above the definition, put it below.  This is a bit more than just a style convention, as python's built-in help and documentation tools can only take advantage of these "docstrings" if they're the first comment (or multi-line string, as is more common, thus the triple quotes) *below* the function definition.

As @talonmies notes, your problem is coming from the fact that you're assuming that you have the same number of positive and negative chunks.  There are several ways around this, but one simple one is to just use `itertools.izip_longest`.

Now, as an example...

```
import random
import itertools
import numpy
import scipy.io.wavfile

def main():
    """Read a wav file and shuffle the negative and positive pieces."""
    # Use unpacking to your advantage, and avoid using "input" as a var name
    samplerate, data = scipy.io.wavfile.read('sample.wav')     

    # Note, my sample.wav is stereo, so I'm going to just work with one channel
    # If yours is mono, you'd want to just pass "data" directly in
    left, right = data.T

    wavchunks = process_wav(left)  
    output = shuffle_wav(wavchunks).astype(numpy.int16)
    print get_fitness(output, samplerate)

    scipy.io.wavfile.write('output.wav', 44100, output)

def process_wav(wavdata):
    """Read a wav file data array, detect zero crossings, 
    split at zero crossings, and return a list of numpy arrays"""

    # I prefer nonzero to where, but either works in this case...
    zerocrossings, = numpy.diff(numpy.sign(wavdata)).nonzero()
    zerocrossings += 1
    indicies = [0] + zerocrossings.tolist() + [None]

    # The key is that we don't need to convert everything to a list.
    # Just pass back a list of views into the array. This uses less memory.
    return [wavdata[i:j] for i, j in zip(indicies[:-1], indicies[1:])]

def shuffle_wav(partitions):
    """Accept a list as input, separate into positive and negative chunks, 
    shuffle, and return a shuffled nested list."""

    # Instead of iterating through each item, just use indexing 
    poschunks = partitions[::2]
    negchunks = partitions[1::2]
    if poschunks[0][0] < 0:
        # Reverse the variable names if the first chunk wasn't positive.
        negchunks, poschunks = poschunks, negchunks

    # Instead of popping a random index off, just shuffle the lists...
    random.shuffle(poschunks)
    random.shuffle(negchunks)

    # To avoid the error you were getting, use izip_longest
    chunks = itertools.izip_longest(poschunks, negchunks, fillvalue=[])

    return numpy.hstack(item for sublist in chunks for item in sublist)


def get_fitness(array, target):
    """Compares sum of square differences between the two arrays."""
    # I'm going to assume that you wanted a single sum returned here...
    # Your original code returned an array.
    return ((array - target)**2).sum()

main()
```

Comment: Thank you, Joe! I've always been scared of itertools, but it's time to learn--it seems to solve a lot of problems. Your style notes were especially useful. I'm slowly learning how to keep things pythonic.